# How to download/show/add images using server in my project?

Tags: android, visual-studio, gridview, server

I have a project that have a gridview inside a fragment showing a list of games that clicking in each will open a new fragment showing the guide for the game.

How can I manage this array from a server to when I upload more images it updates the app gridview with new images?

Actually, what I need is:

- Download and show the images inside the gridview.
- Add images directly to a server, make the app listen the server, when new images were added the app update the list of image and title of the game and show automatically in the gridview.(if possible)

[Gridview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LJOI0.jpg)

```
public class GridGameListFragment extends Fragment {

    private Context context;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;

    GridView gridView;


    public GridListaJogosFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.grid_lista_jogos_fragment, container, false);

      gridView = (GridView) view.findViewById(R.id.gridview_xml);

      CustomGridAdapterGameList adapter = new CustomGridAdapterGameList(getActivity());

       gridView.setAdapter(adapter);

       gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
           @Override
           public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {



               FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
               FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();

               GuideFragment guideFragment = new GuideFragment();

               fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.rl_lista_jogos_activity_xml, guideFragment);
                fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);


               fragmentTransaction.commit();

           }
       });

        return view;
    }

}
```

========================

```
public class CustomGridAdapterGameList extends BaseAdapter {

    private String[] titles = { "Final Fantasy 7",
            "Final Fantasy 8",
            "Final Fantasy 9"

    };
    private int[] covers = { R.drawable.ff7_ps1,
            R.drawable.ff8_ps1,
            R.drawable.ff9_ps1,
    };

    private Context context;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;

    public CustomGridAdapterGameList(Context context){

        this.context = context;

    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return titles.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return titles.length;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        View gridview = convertView;

        if(convertView == null){

            inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            gridview = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_gridview__lista_jogos_layout, null);
        }else{
            gridview= convertView;
        }

        TextView textView = gridview.findViewById(R.id.textview_custom_grid_xml);
        ImageView imageView = gridview.findViewById(R.id.imageview_custom_grid_xml);

        textView.setText(titles[position]);
        imageView.setImageResource(covers[position]);

        return gridview;
    }
}
```

Comment: Any more whishes and questions?

Comment: No, you didn't help with the first ones :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

getview() is called every time you scroll your grid view.
you can download game images using AsyncTask and then setImageResourse

```
private class DownloadImageTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void,Bitmap> {
    ImageView bmImage;

    public DownloadImageTask(ImageView bmImage) {
        this.bmImage = bmImage;
    }

    protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... urls) {
        String urldisplay = urls[0];
        Bitmap bitmap = null;
        try {
            InputStream in = new java.net.URL(urldisplay).openStream();
            bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
        } catch (Exception e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return bitmap;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
        bmImage.setImageBitmap(result);
    }
}
```

It is a good practice if you can cache game images so not downloading them with every scroll

The second question can be solved either by sending a (message) from the server when new image added. Implement a listener to listen to this message. When received, update your GridView
Also you can implement a pull-down-refresh for simpler solution